# What is the meaning of OCB?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, acronyms, obscure-terms

In a scene from the second episode of the TV miniseries *Top of the Lake*, the lead character (a New Zealand police officer) discovers a dead body floating in the sea. She does not enter into the water, but calls for her male companion, and shouts instructions:

> Don't touch him… all right, just bring him into shore. I'm going to have to stay here, I'm OCB.

In a further scene she tries entering into the sea, but experiences sth. that looks like a panic attack and is forced to draw back.

Though I found a couple of terms called OCB, they do not make any sense in this context.

[image: Caption: I'm going to have to stay here. I'm OCB]

Comment: And the terms you found were...? Are you sure it was not OCD?

Comment: Did you hear this term or did you see it written down? Because if the former, it was almost certainly OCD (Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder), not OCB.

Comment: OCD is a much more likely bet than OCB, but it is still a bit odd—OCD does not usually involve a fear of water.

Comment: [This](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Slang/OCB.html) is what I got for OCB, and it _does not_ make sense in this context.

Comment: More sure than whole surinam

Comment: Both, I read the subtitles while hearing the woman saying the same in a clear utterance

Comment: Was the woman pregnant, or trying to get pregnant by any chance?

Comment: There was no indication for it so far, the woman had a flat stomach and was just before discovering the body jogging a long distance, she is also a police woman on duty. The tv show is about a mysterious pregnancy of a 12 year old girl.

Comment: I was asking becaus I found a reference to [Overall Baseline Cortisol](http://www.pnas.org/content/103/10/3938.full), which seems to be an indicator in early preganancy (first 3 weeks, so she would have a flat stomach), and an indicator to watch to avoid losing a fetus.

Comment: The setting is in new Zealand, maybe it is some term limited to this English speaking nation

Comment: I was going to say "Organized Crime Bureau", but New Zealand does not have that: they have OFCANZ and OCA.

Comment: I thought about this, too. But, as you said there is none in new Zealand and if one assumed there was one for practical reasons, the man knew already about her occupation

Comment: I found [this on Word Reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-word-ocb.2695037/), and some of the people answering were from New Zealand (where I got the NZ police info). One said he thought it meant Officer in Charge of Body, but that is not definitive. It is probably one of those acronyms they love to throw around on cop shows to prove they are hip and cool.

Comment: a fictitious acronyme? Like star treks technobabble but for police

Comment: [This forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-word-ocb.2695037/) has the same question, with no resolution.

Comment: @Cascabel - Sorry, I didn't notice your comment earlier.

Comment: @aparente001 No worries. It was set and forget. And your further research made it so much more solid.

Answer (score 1):

OCD doesn't make sense to me here (typically one says *I have OCD and can't go in the water*, or *I have a phobia of going in the water*), so I did some googling.

At https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-word-ocb.2695037/, someone suggested *"Officer in Charge of Body."*  This sounds good to me.  Nice and officious, which police lingo tends to be.  More googling [produced](http://www.ipca.govt.nz/includes/download.aspx?ID=104260):

> Concerns were expressed about the fragmented nature of the liaison with the deceased’s family during the short initial investigation. The role appears to have been shared by the Detectives respectively appointed **Officer in Charge of Body** and Officer in Charge of Suspect.